# Filter Query Result in List and Put in Map

Tags: apex, soql, permissions, list, map

I have been working with ObjectPermissions Object. I need to show entire table on vf Page using SOQL

```
Select **List Fields** From ObjectPermissions Order By Parent.Profile.name
```

With the result i get from the query, i want to filter the result in a map as :

```
 Map{
Profile 1 -->(All Records related to Profile1)
Profile 2 -->(All Records related to Profile2)
Profile 3 -->(All Records related to Profile3)
Profile 4 -->(All Records related to Profile4)    
}
```

What condition should i put to filter the records?

Answer (score 2):

According to how `PermissionSet`, `Profile` and `ObjectPermissions` are connected in SF [data model](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_permissionset.htm), you need to change query object to `PermissionSet` and use `ObjectPerms` child relationship

```
List<PermissionSet> result  = [
    select Profile.Name, (
        select id, PermissionsRead, SobjectType
        from ObjectPerms
        )
    from PermissionSet
    where IsOwnedByProfile = true
    order by Profile.Name
    ];
Map<String, List<ObjectPermissions>> objPermissionsByProfileName =  new Map<String, List<ObjectPermissions>>();
for(PermissionSet permSet :result){
   objPermissionsByProfileName.put(permSet.Profile.Name, permSet.ObjectPerms);
}
```

Using [SOQL for loops](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for_SOQL.htm) no need to have not needed `result` variable:

```
Map<String, List<ObjectPermissions>> objPermissionsByProfileName =  new Map<String, List<ObjectPermissions>>();
    for(PermissionSet permSet :[
        select Profile.Name, (
            select [List Fields]
            from ObjectPerms
            )
        from PermissionSet
        where IsOwnedByProfile = true
        order by Profile.Name
        ]){
        objPermissionsByProfileName.put(permSet.Profile.Name, permSet.ObjectPerms);
    }
```

replace `[List Fields]` with list of desired fields.

so your desired result is stored in `objPermissionsByProfileName` map. `Name` of profile is a key and list of `ObjectPermissions` sobject as a value

Comment: The result i required is not achieved yet.

Comment: Your answer successfully results in a map with profile-names as key-values but i required a list corresponding  to that profile , the list must contain records with that profile name only.